# Can not connect to sails socket

Tags: node.js, socket.io, sails.js, sails.io.js

I am trying to continously broadcast/publish/emit/send messages to a socket room using Sails on my backend, and on another project continously recieve these messages.

Expected behaviour : every time addToSocketAndRedis() is called, i see a console log on my client and on my server (from the controller)

Observed behaviour: Errors + no message
My client code is:

```
var io = require('sails.io.js')(require('socket.io-client'));

// Specify the URL of your Sails server here
io.sails.url = 'http://localhost:1337';
io.socket.get('/subscribeToPrices', function (res) {
    console.log(res);
});
io.socket.on('message', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

And the error i get on the client:

```
====================================
 The socket was unable to connect.
 The server may be offline, or the
 socket may have failed authorization
 based on its origin or other factors.
 You may want to check the values of
 `sails.config.sockets.onlyAllowOrigins`
 or (more rarely) `sails.config.sockets.beforeConnect`
 in your app.
 More info: https://sailsjs.com/config/sockets
 For help: https://sailsjs.com/support

 Technical details:
 TransportError: websocket error
```

*My "onlyAllowOrigins" is commented out as default by Sails, so that is not the issue.*

My Sails code:

**PriceFeedSocketController.js**

```
module.exports = {
    subscribeToPrices: async function (req, res) {
        console.log(`Attempted connection to price sub`)
        if (req.isSocket) {
            console.log(`Connection to price sub`)
            sails.sockets.join(req, 'prices', function (err) {
                if (err) {
                    return res.serverError(err);
                }
                return res.ok();
            });
        } else {
            return res.badRequest();
        }
    }

};
```

**add-to-socket-and-redis.js**

```
module.exports = {
    friendlyName: "Add to socket and redis",
    description: "Adds feed into socket room named `prices` then into redis ",
    inputs: {
        feed: {
            friendlyName: "Data feed",
            description: "List of key value pairs to be inserted and broadcasted",
            type: "json",
            defaultsTo: []
        }
    },
    fn:
        async function (inputs, exits) {
            const feed = inputs.feed;
            sails.sockets.broadcast('prices', feed);
            await sails.helpers.redisInsert.with({
                feed
            })
            return exits.success();
        }
}
```

**routes.js:**

```
module.exports.routes = {
  '/': { view: 'pages/homepage' },
  '/subscribeToPrices': 'PriceFeedSocket.subscribeToPrices',
};
```

**config/security.js**

```
  cors: {
    allRoutes: true,
    allowOrigins: '*',
    allowCredentials: false
  }
```

Comment: What version of `socket.io` are you using?